# Claim Based Authentication and Authorization from Active Directory using Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: authentication, c#-4.0, active-directory, wif

I need to develop a security module which require Authentication from Active Directory and claim based Authorization using **Windows Identity Foundation**. I developed a solution which is working fine with local STS Web Site but i want to do the same thing using Active Directory.

NOTE: User Authentication from AD using **DirectoryServices** is not my Requirement.

It would be really appreciated if anyone Guide me in this regard.

Comment: provide something, some code or anything other, what did you read about it? Did you try to code something?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a WIF based application authenticating OK with a local STS?

To do the same thing with AD, you need a STS that authenticates against AD using WS-Federation.

In the Microsoft world, this is provided by ADFS.

So you need to install ADFS 3.0 (Server 2012 R2) and then configure it.